# Update one entry of each unique Record in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-update

I have a table containing usernames and deleted status. Duplicate username deleted status combination can be possible. If a username has more than one entry with deleted status as 1 then I need to update deleted status to 0 for one entry of each username.

Consider the following data:

```
Name  EmpId  Deleted
--------------------
A     01     1
A     01     1
B     02     1
B     02     0
C     03     1
```

Requirement: One entry of Names A and C should be updated to 0 (Deleted status).

```
declare @testTable table (Name varchar(10), EmpId varchar(10), Deleted tinyint)

insert into @testTable
select 'A', '01', 1 UNION ALL
select 'A', '01', 1 UNION ALL
select 'B', '02', 1 UNION ALL
select 'B', '02', 0 UNION ALL
select 'C', '03', 1

select * from @testTable
```

Comment: Did you try anything on your own?

Comment: I couldn’t write an update for this, so I inserted a new entry for each username which doesn’t had a 0 status.

Comment: You wrote: "more than one entry with deleted status as 1" and then you wrote: "Requirement: One entry of Names A and C should be updated to 0 (Deleted status)." Why C should be deleted? We have in your example only one entry of name "C"

Comment: @RomanBadiornyi: I found same issue, contradictory. I answered below to update duplicates only.

Comment: Your life would be so much easier with UNIQUE ID column in this table.

Comment: Are you actually trying to undelete users who do not have single active entry? This is `not exists` kind of job then.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
;with cte as
(
  select name, empId, deleted, 
         row_number() over (partition by name, empId order by deleted desc) rn
  from T
)
Update cte set deleted = 0
where rn <> 1 and deleted = 1
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49984/8)

Comment: I think the 5th row, i.e. C will not get updated. Please confirm.

Comment: In your given data example, `C` is *NOT* duplicated that is why.

Comment: Yes, description is not perfect. I need to update the record for C also. Good logic any way.

Comment: So, what is the updated logic? if you just need to update `C` regardless any logic, then you could add `Or name = 'C'` to the *Where* clause

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name, deleted order by deleted) as seqnum
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set deleted = 0
    where deleted = 1 and seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

[SqlFillde demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e0bb/1)

```
with t1 as 
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
           (PARTITION BY EMPID order by deleted) as rn
       from testtable
)
update t1 set deleted=0 where rn=1 and deleted=1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @testTable table 
(
    Name varchar(10), 
    EmpId varchar(10), 
    Deleted tinyint
)

insert into @testTable
select 'A', '01', 1 UNION ALL
select 'A', '01', 1 UNION ALL
select 'A', '01', 1 UNION ALL
select 'B', '02', 1 UNION ALL
select 'B', '02', 0 UNION ALL
select 'B', '02', 0 UNION ALL
select 'C', '03', 1

select * from @testTable
update @testTable set deleted=1
BEGIN
with t1 as 
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
           (PARTITION BY EMPID order by deleted) as rn
       from @testTable
)
update t1 set deleted=0 where rn=1 and deleted=1
END
select * from @testTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    UPDATE A
    SET Deleted = (CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN 0 ELSE Deleted END)
    FROM
    (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Deleted) AS RowNum
    FROM @testTable A WHERE Name NOT IN (SELECT Name FRom @testTable B Where Deleted=0)
    ) A
```